# WinDBG Preview - Load source code from other visual studio projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, windbg

I have an asp.net windows service application with the following structure:
[(solution image into visual studio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibeDw.jpg)

I'm using WinDbg Preview and I'm able to attatch it to the SyncService process.

But when I try to debug it, I'm only able to open the source code for the SyncService project... Is it possible to debug the source code for the other projects ? Because all the logic of the application is outside of the SyncService project.

In the folder where the service is published, there are DLL and PDB files for all the projects.

I've tried to load the DLL and PDB files (using the ".load" command) but without success... when I execute "x *!" to list all the modules, it only show the SyncService.exe.

I can insert break points to the SyncService.cs class, but when I open a class of another project and try to add a break point, nothing happens...

Update 1 - I'm able to insert break points into other classes than SyncService.cs via command line with the SOS lib, but I can only reach them via command line, is there a way to "link" the source code files ?

Comment: Does [`lm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/lm--list-loaded-modules-) shows the all modules being loaded in the process address space? can you see them with their PDB loaded properly (even if marked as `deferred`)? if yes have you tried to use[`.srcpath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/source-window) and other related commands?